# How do I disable the drop-down spell check box?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, keyboard, auto-correct, spell-check

I just updated my Galaxy S4 to Android 5.0.1/Lollipop. I don't like to use the drop-down spell check/autocorrect box; I prefer the one built into the Google Keyboard that displays as a line of suggestions above the keyboard. The drop-down displays over that line so I have to back out of it to tap a suggestion.

I had it disabled on Android 4.4.2/Kitkat and cannot figure out how to turn it off in 5. I've toggled all settings under Google Keyboard and Samsung keyboard to no avail. The only way I could find to disable it was to force close the Samsung keyboard, but unfortunately I can't permanently disable it.

Thanks!

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of drop-down keyboard]

Comment: I've given up and will just live with it...I don't think this option can be turned off in Android 5.

Answer (score 2):

I managed how to disable the Lollipop's spell checker, (not one from keyboards as in other answers).

Just go to, **Settings** → **Language & input** → **Spell checker** then switch it off.

Already done ;)

Answer (score 1):

**On the Galaxy A 5**, go to : Settings -> Language and Input -> Samsung Keyboard Settings -> and switch "Predictive text" to off.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have Google Keyboard installed in Play Store. This keyboard somehow done all the spell checking despite the fact that I couldn't find it in settings, I wasn't even aware I had it installed. After uninstalling Google Keyboard spell checking turned off.
(not my advice, I checked it on http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s5/514492-spell-check-won-t-turn-off.html)

Comment: Well, it did turn off spell checking (the red underlines) but not the drop-down. Thanks!

Comment: To disable spell check you just need to disable Google Keyboard (GBoard - Google Keyboard). It works if you use different keyboard, for instance, SwiftKey (as I do actually).

Answer (score 0):

The drop down bugged me for ages too as I would go to tap the correct word along the top of the keyboard and the drop down overlay would always pop up in the way and I would hit the wrong thing.

Here's how I solved it:

`Settings` > `Language & Input` > `Google Keyboard` (It was the 2nd option under Keyboard & Input Methods for me) > `Gesture Typing` > switch off `Dynamic Floating Preview`.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Note 4: Go to **Settings → Controls→ Language and input**, and make sure that default is set to **Samsung Keyboard**.

Under that, tap on **Samsung Keyboard** to open it. Scroll down, tap **Predictive text** to open, and move the slider (in the top right corner) to off.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I've come to the conclusion that, at least in Android 5 on my Galaxy S4, there is no way to disable the spell checker. I've been trying to just adjust my correction method to use the drop-down.